# Why can't browserify use my module?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I made a library, bundled it with browserify, put it here: https://github.com/cfv1984/two-ways and published a module from it.

The library as compiled works just fine in the browser, the package I made from it is unusable as you can see by installing it and having a test file like this:

```
var two = require('two-ways');
console.log("Two", two);
```

And running it through

```
browserify test.file.js > test.compiled.js
```

What am I doing wrong? The error message I get, `Error: Cannot find module './../../util/makeGetter' from 'D:\o\puto\node_modules\two-ways'`makes 0 sense in this context, because I don't actually have a file in there any more, but a bundle, which as far as I can tell browserify was OK with generating.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browserify was mis-packing the file after transmogrifying it through Babel, so I simply used Webpack to package with which made it self-consistent again and I can use it with browserify and/or webpack or any other bundling software without much issue.